# Assign characterAtIndex to characterAtIndex

Tags: objective-c

```
[a characterAtIndex:0] = [b characterAtIndex:0];
```

i want to assing charAt a to charAt b.

but failed, how?

Answer (score 0):

```
  NSMutableString *a = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"HOUSE" ];

  NSString *b= @"MUSIC";

 [a replaceCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0, 1) withString:[b substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 1)]];
```

As a result you get MOUSE ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking a method something like this: `setCharacter:atIndex:`

Then look at the code below:

```
NSMutableString *string=[NSMutableString stringWithString:@"abcdefgh"];

[string setCharacter:'X' atIndex:0]; //Note X is character not string so "X" and its is primitive therefore even @ is not prefixed.

NSLog(@"%@",string);
```

This is acheived by a category on `NSMutableString` whose method implements

```
@implementation NSMutableString (SetCharacterAtIndex)

- (void)setCharacter:(char)character atIndex:(NSUInteger)index;{

    [self replaceCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(index, 1) withString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",character]];

}
```

Edit:

After having the above method, you can use :

<strike>[a characterAtIndex:0] = [b characterAtIndex:0];</strike>

```
[a setCharacter:[b characterAtIndex:0] atIndex:0];
```